# Add prefix to a html rendered string

Tags: markdown

I want to add a `For` before a html rendered string for ex:
str = `<h2><strong>this is remark 11</strong></h2><p>address</p>`
and the output of the following is

### **this is remark 11**

address

and now I want to add `For` before the `this is remark 11` sentence. So the expected output is:-

For **this is remark 11**

address

So how do I add the display inline block into the `str` h2 tag and is there any other way to do so.

Comment: <h2>For <strong>this is remark 11</strong></h2><p>address</p>